# Gulp error on font awesome css

Tags: css, gulp, font-awesome, gulp-concat

I have been working on a react project. When I added react-fa component as a node module, my gulp started throwing an error and the changes I made afterward are not getting reflected in the published folder.

Here is my console[image]

This is the error I am getting

```
E:\Ajanth\sample\node_modules\font-awesome\css\font-awesome.css:7
@font-face {
^
ParseError: Unexpected character '@'
```

Here are my gulp js imports and config

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect'); //Runs a local dev server
var open = require('gulp-open'); //Open a URL in a web browser
var browserify = require('browserify'); // Bundles JS
var reactify = require('reactify');  // Transforms React JSX to JS
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream'); // Use conventional text streams with Gulp
var concat = require('gulp-concat'); //Concatenates files
var lint = require('gulp-eslint'); //Lint JS files, including JSX

var config = {
    port: 9005,
    devBaseUrl: 'http://localhost',
    paths: {
        html: './src/*.html',
        js: './src/**/*.js',
        images: './src/images/*',
        css: [
            'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
            'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css',
            'node_modules/toastr/toastr.css',
            'node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
            './src/css/custom.css',
            'node_modules/react-data-components/css/table-twbs.css'
        ],
        dist: './dist',
        fonts: 'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*',
        mainJs: './src/main.js'
    }
}
```

Here is the gulp task for css

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src(config.paths.css)
        .pipe(concat('bundle.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/css'));
});
```

I tried adding the gulp-concat-css node module and used `concatCss` instead of `concat` in the task. But still getting the same error and the css is not getting minified too.

I even tried removing the font-awesome css from the path of css files to be minified as well. But still getting the same error.

I am stuck with it. Please help me figure out what the issue is and fix it so that the gulp task will run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up your extracted `font-awesome.css` in dist/css you will see in the first block in @font-face where the src is pointing to looking for the fonts. There must be the corresponding fonts in that directory in dist/fonts.

You are not extracting your font-awesome fonts with gulp. You have the path in your config for the fonts but you should add this gulp task:

```
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    gulp.src(config.paths.fonts)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/fonts'));
});
```